# After adding a tab control and copying and pasting the text fields + buttons into a tab my windows form no longer works

Tags: winforms, crud, tabcontrol

I'm a C# noobie and have recently made a CRUD app with windows forms and decided to upgrade it a little by adding a tab function to add new functionalities to it but after copying and pasting the design of my windows form into the TabControl field, the design shows up but the CRUD system itself no long works.

I feel like I might need to call the TabControl in the form design code but have no idea how I'd do that. All of my CRUD code was made directly on the WinForm design class.

Comment: When you paste the controls into the new Tab the will NOT have any events wired up for them.  You'll have to either select each control and re-attach the events to existing methods, or write new methods for them if they should do something different.

Comment: What are you copy/pasting from and to? In addition, what does _”no longer works”_ mean? Are there errors? You need to keep in mind that if you copy/paste controls into the same form… then the paste will change the names of the pasted controls.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I appreciate the quick help, it's just as you mentioned, after copying and pasting the event handler properties were lost. After wiring them back everything is working perfectly! :D

Comment: @JohnG nothing was responsive, so no error messages. Turns out the event handlers were wiped from the forms properties. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Just make sure if you have multiple controls firing the same method you use the `sender` parameter correctly to know which control was the source of the event.

Answer (score 0):

As @Idle_Mind mentioned in the comments, after pasting controls into the new tab all the events wired to them were wiped. After rewiring them the problem was solved!